# What does "Processing for App Store" mean

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, app-store

Hi guys I uploaded a game to App Store and I set the version release to be released automatically at date and time. But at that time I only got 2 mails first one was that my game is "Ready for sale" and the second one that came right after the first one it changed to "Processing for App Store". Wheres the point why wasn't my app released at the set time? They already sent me an email where they said that the game was approved.

Answer (score 1):

It takes time to distribute your app across Apple's servers.

Also, using a process called [app thinning](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/404/), multiple versions of your app are built.

For things like the above, Apple has reserved this extra state called 'Processing for App Store'.

No worries, it won't take long, a few hours at most, before your app will appear in people's App Store.